# Trying to get this script to work but keep getting this error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import datetime
import pytz
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from PIL import Image

# Set timezone to UK time
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')

picam2 = Picamera2()
picam2.configure("still")
picam2.start()

# Give time for Aec and Awb to settle, before disabling them
time.sleep(1)
picam2.set_controls({"AeEnable": False, "AwbEnable": False, "FrameRate": 1.0})
# And wait for those settings to take effect
time.sleep(1)

start_time = time.time()

while True:
    # Get current time in UK time zone
    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz)

    # Check if it's daytime in the UK
    if now.hour >= 8 and now.hour < 18:
        # Capture image
        r = picam2.capture_request()
        while not r.completed:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        image = Image.frombytes(r.image_format, r.image_size, r.image)

        # Save image with day count in filename
        filename = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_Day%j.jpg")
        image.save(filename)

        print(f"Captured image {filename} at {now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}")

        # Wait until next day
        next_day = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        sleep_time = (next_day - now).total_seconds()
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
    else:
        # Wait until daytime
        next_daytime = now.replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
        if now.hour >= 18:
            next_daytime += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        sleep_time = (next_daytime - now).total_seconds()
        time.sleep(sleep_time)

picam2.stop()
```

i get this error "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/cam/cam.py", line 31, in 
while not r.completed:
AttributeError: 'CompletedRequest' object has no attribute 'completed'"

i tried using wait and this "Tyrone D
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/cam/cam.py", line 31, in 
r.wait()
AttributeError: 'CompletedRequest' object has no attribute 'wait'"

if anyone could help wold be great thanks

trying to make a scrip that takes one photo everyday and get the error abovve

Comment: I don't see any mention of `.completed` in the documentation. And `.wait()` is a method of `picam2`, not `r`.

Comment: You can find the documentation [here](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/camera/picamera2-manual.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the lines

```py
while not r.completed:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

as the call to `picam2.capture_request()` only returns when it is done capturing. From the [documentation](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/camera/picamera2-manual.pdf#page=37) (emphasis mine):

> All the capture and switch_mode_and_capture methods take two additional arguments:
>
> - `wait` - whether to block while the operation completes
> - `signal_function` - a function that will be called when the operation completes.
>
> Both take the default value None, but can be changed resulting in the following behaviour:
>
> - If `wait` and `signal_function` are both None, then **the function will block until the operation is complete**. This is what we would probably term the "usual" behaviour.